# proftpd: distinguish daemon instances running

Tags: process, configuration, proftpd

On my machine I've configured 2 instances of ProFTPd daemon with:

- 2  different PidFile
- 2 different listening port (21 & 2100)
- 2 different list of allowed users/path/permission/...

Everything is working as expected but the problem that I have to distinguish them on processlist as both are shown with same name:

```
> ps -ef | grep ftp
nobody   22480     1  0 09:31 ?        00:00:00 proftpd: (accepting connections)
nobody   24545     1  0 09:41 ?        00:00:00 proftpd: (accepting connections)
```

Is there a way to distinguish them with 2 different names in order to be able to kill and restart only one of them and not both?

Answer (score 1):

You might combine the `ps` output with `lsof`, *e.g.* `lsof -p <proftpd-pid>`, and use `lsof`'s output to see the listening port/address, and so distinguish the processes that way.